# Changing Membership.ValidateUser() and other things in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to change the ValidateUser method in MVC 3?
For example.. require an additional parameter like an identification number or something like that?
I get the feeling this stuff is quite static...

Oh and is there a way to use another database than the existing mdf+ldf SQL database (for example a MySQL DB)?

**Edit:
I'm still having trouble with setting this stuff up.**

In my BOMembershipProvider class I have

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace MVCTests
{
    public class BOMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        public override string ApplicationName
```

and so on.
It's located in my App_Data folder.
My Web.config looks like this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="BOMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
          <clear/>
          <add name="BOMembershipProvider" type="BOMembershipProvider"
               connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
               enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
               enablePasswordReset="true"
               requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
               requiresUniqueEmail="false"
               maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
               minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
               minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
               passwordAttemptWindow="10"
               applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
```

It's still giving me the error with the type not found thing. Any hints, solutions, ...?

Oh and I tried that with MVCTests.BOMembershipProvider in the Web.config too, with no results :(

Comment: Where you specify type in your Web.Config I think you need to include the full namespace. So type="MVCTests.BOMembershipProvider" See this link: http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2007/12/30/118071.aspx

Comment: and your test project would also need to reference your MVC project where you created BOMembershipProvider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a custom Membership provider to change the behavior of ValidateUser. This will also enable you to use a different database provider.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx or google asp.net custom membership provider.

This example of a custom membership provider that uses entity framework codefirst helped me to get started:

http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/